# How can I represent a matrix in Github markdown?

Tags: mathjax, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to represent a basic vector, the following code works in Visual Studio Code.

I am using the following line `$\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix}$`

All whitespace removed. It should look like this,

[image]

However, when pushed to Github it does not render correctly and instead just renders to entire text letter for letter like it is unsupported. Does anybody know how to get get the following vector to display correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LaTeX matrix not rendering correctly on Github Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74203840/latex-matrix-not-rendering-correctly-on-github-markdown)

Answer (score 3):

just replace `\\` with `\\\`

`\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix} X \\\ Y \end{bmatrix}`

Comment: I couldn't get the column separators of & to work though even with escaping attempts. I could only get it to work in a ```math block